# AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'load' python3.6

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm trying to load JSON from a file into python, but I keep receiving the error:

> AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'load'

I don't have files called json.py in my directory like other answers suggested.

When I do:

```
import json;
print(json.__file__)
/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py
```

I receive:

> /usr/lib/python3.6/json/**init**.py

I have checked the file and it does contain the methods.

The full script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json;
print(json.__file__)
import sys;


#a = json.load('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
#pprint(a);

#sys.exit();

from pprint import pprint;

with open('services.json') as f:
        data=json.load(f);

pprint(data);
```

I'm kinda losing my mind here. When I change the shebang to python2.7 it does work, however, I have written my other scripts with python3.6.

Help would be very much appreciated!

**Solution:** I named the file 'enum.py', changing the name removes the error.

Comment: No, that's the strange thing. I stated that in my question by the way, I have a couple files, the only thing that comes close is 'services.json' which is the actual file I want to load.

Comment: Use the python3 interpreter and try from there.

Comment: Make sure you don't have some other object called json in the program, like a function or variable.  I guess it would have to be a module... try dir(json) to see if load is in the list.

Comment: @musikreck When I try to use python3.6 from a shell in another directory, it works. However, when I load it in the directory and try to import json I get the same error. The only files I have are: __pycache__  auto-recon.py  enum.py  services.json  threads.py. Any idea what might be the cause of this?

Comment: @jeffpkamp The code above is everything, it's not being imported currently. The error happens based on running the file solely.  dir(json):
['JSONDecodeError', 'JSONDecoder', 'JSONEncoder', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_default_decoder', '_default_encoder', 'codecs', 'decoder', 'detect_encoding', 'dump', 'dumps', 'encoder', 'load', 'loads', 'scanner']

Comment: Guys I figured it out, thank you for the help. Apparently, naming the file 'enum.py' was a bad choice as there is an enum.py in the python3.6 directory: __/usr/lib/python3.6/enum.py__ which is somehow being used. When I changed the name the code worked. Talk about bad luck. Have a nice one!

Answer (score 1):

just use simplejson lib. worked for me

```
import simplejson
```